# Simple sticky menu issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a simple sticky menu. But currently i am facing 2 problems with it. Here is the link to the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3xz9xxdJnI

First Issue:

I have set margin: 0 auto and yet the div does not align itself to the center of the body. Can any one reason it out. and suggest a solution

Second Issue:

Even though i have not set any padding between anchor (a) tag there is a small padding that automatically comes up. Y does this happen and what is the solution for it.

Regards,

Maclean Maurice Pinto

Comment: jsfiddle link is broken.

Comment: nope its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Fix the wrapper to the bottom, and align the bar inside the wrapper to the middle.

```
.wrap{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%
}
 .botbar {
     margin:0 auto;
     background-color:#FF5900;
     height:70px;
     border-radius: 15px;

 }
```

To get rid of the space between a's it seems floating the a elements left works

```
float:left;
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this. It works fine. Yet my question was why does the botbar div does align to the center. secondly y there is a padding between anchor tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
 style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;"
```

use this style and change the width

```
<div class="botbar" align="center" style="width:500px; margin:0 auto;">
```

delete width in your css file